# Why file_put_contents is not working in register_shutdown_function?

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error, custom-error-handling, file-put-contents

I'm creating an error handler, but I have a dark trouble...
After runing my code, I see this in my monitor:

> Function is working!
>
> Fatal error: Class 'NotExistingClass' not found in 
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\models_statistic\run.php on
>   line 39
>
> Handler is working! 
>   Function is working!

But in logging_error.txt I see just:

> [29-03-2016 20:52:54] 0 : Logger is working! in  on line

...without this Fatal error oO

```
    <?php

    ignore_user_abort(true);

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    set_time_limit(0);

    set_error_handler('error_handler');

    register_shutdown_function('fatal_error_handler');

    function log_error($errno, $message, $file, $line)
    {
        echo 'Function is working!';
        file_put_contents('logging_error.txt', '['.date('d-m-Y').' '.date('H:i:s').'] '.$errno.' : '.$message.' in '.$file.' on line '.$line."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }

    function error_handler($errno, $message, $file, $line)
    {
        if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {           
            return;
        }
        log_error($errno, $message, $file, $line);
    }

    function fatal_error_handler()
    {
        $last_error = error_get_last();
        if ($last_error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
            // fatal error
            echo 'Handler is working!';
            error_handler(E_ERROR, $last_error['message'], $last_error['file'], $last_error['line']);
        }
    }

    error_log(0, 'Logger is working!', '', '');
    class SomeClass extends NotExistingClass {}
```

Comment: Try `==` instead of `===` in `fatal_error_handler`

Comment: but error_hadler is starting and log_error function is starting too. All working, only file_put_contents is not work

Comment: So... have you made sure that `fatal_error_handler` works too?

Comment: Yes. After runing my code, I see this in my monitor:

Function is working!

Fatal error: Class 'NotExistingClass' not found in D:\OpenServer\domains\models_statistic\run.php on line 39

Handler is working! Function is working!
But in logging_error.txt I see just:

[29-03-2016 20:52:54] 0 : Logger is working! in on line
...without this Fatal error oO

Comment: Is this running on command line? If so give the command you're using.

Comment: No, I trying it in browser